# Filter data based on ID

Tags: mysql, sql, filter

I'd like to be able to filter the following data based on the companyID column:

```
companyID | title | address
    1         a        a
    1         b        b
    1         c        c
    2         d        d
    3         e        e
```

Here is my sql query but it didn't work.

```
$ID = $_GET['id'];
$valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE companyID = '$ID' CONCAT(`title`) LIKE '%" . $valueToSearch ."%'";
```

Comment: Please try it and let me know

Comment: Are you populating `GET` and `POST`? You are open to SQL injections. The `CONCAT` doesn't make sense and you need and `AND` or `OR` to join the two conditions.

Comment: Is this a syntax issue?

Comment: @chris85  
By the way what is SQL Injection?

Comment: `SQL injection is a code injection technique, used to attack data-driven applications, in which nefarious SQL statements are inserted into an entry field for execution (e.g. to dump the database contents to the attacker).`-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection Since you are just putting user data directly into your query you are opening yourself to this. Use parameterized queries. Also use error reporting, the missing `AND` would have thrown an error.

Comment: thank you @chris85 for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As $ID is of integer type, you should remove quotations around it.
2. For searching in `title` column, you dont need `CONCAT`.

   ```
   $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE `companyID` = $ID AND `title` LIKE '%" . $valueToSearch ."%'";
   ```

Comment: I haven't voted but the quotes won't make a difference.

Comment: Nothing change.

Comment: Hi @BehradKhodayar work perfect i forgot to put 'AND' :D

Comment: By the way what is SQL Injection?

Comment: @MOJOJO So, please accept the answer to approve it works.

Comment: @MOJOJO Then get to know about SQL injection : <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection>